When does the compactness of $A^2$ implies the compactness of $A$
The question is the following:
If $A^2$ is compact operator on a Hilbert space and if $A$ is self-adjoint, then $A$ is compact.
My approach was that since $A^2$ is compact, $A^2(x_n)$ has convergent subsequence for every bounded sequence $(x_n)$. And $A$ is not compact, then there is bounded sequence $(y_n)$ such that $A(y_n)$ has no convergent subsequence. The my intution is that one can find a bounded sequence $(z_n)$ such that $A(z_n)$=$(y_n)$ and hence $A^2(z_n)$=$A(y_n)$ which has no convergent subsequence. But, this contradicts the fact that $A^2$ is compact. Hence, $A$ is compact.
I think my solution is not correct because I have not used the self-adjoint property of $A$. Can anyone help me clarify my doubts.
Thanks in advance.

If you want to argue with sequences like in your approach, notice that $$\lVert Ax\rVert^2=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\langle A^2x,x\rangle\leq\lVert A^2 x\rVert\lVert x\rVert.$$ So if $(x_n)$ is bounded and $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence such that $A^2x_{n_k}$ converges, then the above inequality shows that $Ax_{n_k}$ is Cauchy, hence also converges.

The selfadjointness (or normality) is essential. Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis. Define the operator $A$ by $Ae_{2n-1}=0$ and $Ae_{2n}=e_{2n-1}.$ In other words
$$Ax=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{2n}e_{2n-1},\quad x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ne_n$$ Then $A^2=0.$ The operator $A$ is not compact because $Ae_{2n}$ does not admit a convergent subsequence.

@ Ryszard Szwarc I am not understanding how one can guarantee $b_n^2$=$a_n$.

$Av_n=b_nv_n$ implies $$b_n^2=|Av_n|^2=\langle A^2v_n,v_n\rangle =a_n$$

Hi! Sorry to ask, but it is not entirely clear to me why there exist $b_n$ such that the second equality is true. The $v_n$ form an eigenbasis for $A^2$ (mod kernel perhaps), but why are they eigenvectors for $A$? Somehow we have to use selfadjointness for this, but it is not obvious to me.

Thanks for finding the error. My claim holds provided that $a_n$ are single eigenvalues which means that the eigenspaces are one dimensional. The reasoning can be modified but it will be a far reaching overkill I will remove the first part and leave only the second. I suggest, if I may, accepting the one line answer by @leoli1
